# Sharepoint & sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, copy-item

I am currently using SharePoint 2010 and designer 2010 (not by choice:))

I am trying to do the following:

I have a list where people have to create new item and then complete the information fields in the new item. Once they click save it then send a email to me informing me that there is a new item. This is our request for service list.

I then have to create a new item in another list in another library and re-enter some of the information already entered in step A.

How can I go about automating this process. When the person creates a new item and entered the information that when the click save is not only send me the email to inform me that a new request was logged but also then create and new list in the second library and populate some of the corresponding fields with the same data instead of me having to do so manually.

Comment: Hi christian, did you get this working?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the requirement using the Workflow.

You need to add two actions.

1. Send Email
2. Create List Item

Refer to the link below to send an email. Similarly you can create the list Item.

[Send an Email when Item is created](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre)

You need to edit the steps in both the actions as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to do, here are some screen shots to get you started.  You'll need to test this simply to begin with, configure the workflow to copy across a single field value to the destination list.  Then once that works correctly, gradually add fields and test until you have all of the required fields.

Make sure the workflow Start Conditions are correctly configured - if you want the copy to only occur once, then set it to run on **item creation** only in your 'source' List.

(My list is called OH light duties tracker).  I use an [Impersonation Step](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35069/sharepoint-2010-workflows-impersonation-steps-and-security), but you might not need to, it depends on your requirements.  Once you have configured and tested your workflow, if other users find they can not get it to work, you might want to consider using an Impersonation Step.

Anyway, use the:

`Create Item` action in your workflow and select the Destination list, to where you want the new item to be copied.

[image: copy item workflow]

Next, match up fields from the source list to the destination list (just begin with one field and see if it copies over.

[image: field matching]